# What are these items in this 16th century plan of an English town?

Tags: england, identification, early-modern, maps

This plan or picture map of [Great Yarmouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Yarmouth) is from the reign of [Elizabeth I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_I_of_England) (1558-1603). According to the [Norfolk Record Office](http://www.archives.norfolk.gov.uk/download/ncc099572) (pdf),

> It shows the town’s defences at the time of the Spanish Armada in
>   1588. Its depiction of the town’s layout is not wholly accurate (the streets, for example, were laid out in a grid-like pattern), but the
>   marketplace and St Nicholas’s Church are easily identifiable.

[image]

*(click on image to enlarge) This image is taken from the British Library site which gives c.1585 as the date and refers only to "proposed harbour works". [Source: British Library](https://prints.bl.uk/products/picture-map-of-great-yarmouth-008768).*

Daniel Defoe gave a [description of Great Yarmouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Yarmouth) in his *[A tour thro' the whole island of Great Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_tour_thro%27_the_whole_island_of_Great_Britain)* (1724-27) but does not seem to mention No.2 so maybe these had disappeared by then (?).

- What are people with the large 'wheel' doing (blue number 1)?
- What are the structures (blue numbers 2)?

---

*Note: In case anyone is curious, the ship with the flag with black and white horizontal stripes would appear to be from the [Belgian commune of Waimes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Waimes.svg)*

Comment: (2) might be related to [salt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marais_salants_de_Guérande) or some variation of [Garum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garum) production. Another possibility is it being [tannery](https://journals.openedition.org/adlfi/1372) (as is [still done in Fez](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-africa-north-africa-morocco-fes-fs-el-bali-old-fes-medina-old-town-24319067.html)) or simply [lavoir](https://www.alamyimages.fr/photo-image-dhobi-ghats-lavoir-mumbai-inde-37997759.html) related. Had they been vertical they could also have been dovecotes.

Comment: I suspect that the workers by the Southgate are digging a shallow water well. The wheel could help evacuate earth and then retrieve the digger.

Comment: Your hunch about them being fish traps might also be correct. Anecdotally, I'd go fishing crab and shrimps in man-made basins as a child during summers.

Comment: Could number 1 possibly be a trebuchet?

Comment: The 2's are both at navigational pinch points and look like defensive fortifications to me.  They are not there now tho: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Great+Yarmouth,+UK/@52.5727983,1.7344465,467m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d0a98a6c1ed5df:0xa324a38976d3e6a!8m2!3d52.598233!4d1.728047

Comment: I wonder if 1 could be related to peat cutting that occurred in that period around Great Yarmouth that a later flooded and formed the Norfolk Broads?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bigger version of this map here: http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/onlineex/unvbrit/g/zoomify82848.html

No.1 is a wheel with a crank on it and the two men appear to be holding a cable so perhaps it's used to pull boats down that canal.

No.2 is almost certainly some kind of sea defence. It doesn't have guns on it so could be like a sea wall, designed to protect the entrance of the estuary from erosion. The stand alone one on the river is possibly a wall to protect ships at anchor near Little Yarmouth. The black could indicate infill of rocks or dirt.

What's also interesting is the crane near the bridge. I guess this has a practical purpose but it appears that it's being used here to entertain people with a person being hoisted into the air while others run around the base.